# Polymorphic Serialization/Deserialization using Jackson with no Type Property

Tags: java, json, xml, serialization, jackson

After having invested a lot of hours in more than couple of days, I am finally giving up on this. But just to make sure that I am not missing anything, I would like to have your opinion.

So the example xml looks like this

```xml
<Query>
    <SpecialFilter1>
        <SpecialExpression1>some_text</SpecialExpression1>
        <SpecialExpression1>some_text</SpecialExpression1>
        <SpecialExpression2>some_other_text</SpecialExpression2>
        <SpecialExpression2>some_other_text</SpecialExpression2>
    </SpecialFilter1>
    <SpecialFilter2>
        <SpecialExpression1>some_text</SpecialExpression1>
    </SpecialFilter2>
</Query>
```

Accompanying sample code is here in a Github Gist [**https://goo.gl/nwJWfs**](https://goo.gl/nwJWfs)

The **restriction** with XML for me is, it is not possible to have some attribute or other element to specify class information for deserialization. That is why it has to be solved purely via code.

This code fails at deserialization because query class does not have information about property "SpecialFilter1", it only knows about base class.

I have tried many permuation-combinations for `JsonTypeInfo.Id` and `JsonTypeInfo.As`. I also tried both custom `JsonTypeIdResolver` and `JsonTypeResolverBuilder`.

In the end I got partial success with combination of custom `JsonTypeResolverBuilder` and `DeserializationProblemHandler`, by using  `findContextualValueDeserializer()` of deserialization context in `handleUnknownProperty()`. But this looks very dirty and also serialization has its own zillion issues in this way.

**Update 1:**
After having rejected the `BeanDeserialzerModifier` previously, now I wonder if there is a way to modify something to solve this?